# Negation Marking with Regular Expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I'm struggling to implement negation marking using regex in Python, a la Christopher Potts' [sentiment analysis tutorial](http://sentiment.christopherpotts.net/lingstruc.html#fig:tokenizer_accuracy_neg).

The definition of a negation, taken from his tutorial is:

```
(?:
    ^(?:never|no|nothing|nowhere|noone|none|not|
        havent|hasnt|hadnt|cant|couldnt|shouldnt|
        wont|wouldnt|dont|doesnt|didnt|isnt|arent|aint
    )$
)
|
n't
```

and the definition of clause-level punctuation is:

```
^[.:;!?]$
```

The idea is to capture words between a negation and clause-level punctuation and then to modify them to indicate that they are being negated, eg:

```
No one enjoys it.
```

should become something like:

```
No one_NEG enjoys_NEG it_NEG.
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sentence as a string, as you imply, then you can't use '^' and '$' in your regexps. Use `\b` instead. Then this should work:

```
def add_negation_markers(m):
    return m.group(1) + re.sub(r'(?<=\w)\b', '_NEG', m.group(2))
re.sub('(' + neg_re + ')(.*)(?=' + punct_re + ')', add_negation_markers, text)
```

If you have a sentence as a list of words, as `$` and `^` marks imply, then...

```
def negate(word):
    if re.search(punct_re, word):
        negate.should = False
    elif re.search(neg_re, word):
        negate.should = True
    elif negate.should:
        return word + '_NEG'
    return word
negate.should = False
map(negate, words)
```